# Domain (subgroup) estimation in a stratified random sample

Tags: survey, survey-sampling, survey-weights

I want to ask a question about domain estimation (i.e., estimation of a parameter among subpopulations) in a stratified random sample.

It seems to me that in a stratified random sample, domain estimation can be easily done for sampling strata, because within each stratum the sample is an independent random sample. However, if one wants to estimate a parameter in subpopulations defined by variables NOT used in forming the sampling strata, though the point estimates are correct, it is not straightforward with the calculation of standard errors, because the sampling weights cannot be directly applied in this situation (because the sum of sampling weights for this particular subsample does not necessarily equal to the total number of people in this subpopulation).

How can domain estimation be achieved in this situation? Is recalculating sampling weights based on subpopulation totals in each stratum the only way to solve this issue (provided the subpopulation totals are available)?

Any thoughts or feedbacks would be much appreciated!

Here is an example using `r` `survey` package:

```
library(survey)
data(api)

# stratified sample
dstrat <- svydesign(id=~1, strata=~stype, weights=~pw, data=apistrat, fpc=~fpc)

svymean(~enroll, dstrat) # estimate the mean among the whole population

svyby(~enroll, by = ~stype, dstrat, svymean) # estimate the mean among each stratum population

svyby(~enroll, by = ~awards, dstrat, svymean) # estimate the mean among subpopulations defined by awards; this doesn't seem reasonable
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I find the answer to my question:
Based on the following book, it can be done easily with `survey` package, as I did in my question post.

> Lumley T. Chapter 2: Simple and stratified sampling. Complex surveys :
> a guide to analysis using R.